# Forgot openvpn admin's password

Tags: amazon-ec2, vpn, openvpn

I had installed open-vpn on AWS ec2 instance but now I forgot the admin password and I can not access to the openvpn web-ui. Is there any way to reset admin's password?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**Solved:**
connect to the openvpn server appliance using ssh as

```
ssh -i "vpn.pem" openvpnas@public-ip
sudo su -
passwd openvpn
```

You just need to reset openvpn user's password on server and try login on web-ui login page